# Design Pattern name for Delegate + Partial Override

Tags: java, design-patterns

I found myself dumbstruck trying to name a class with the following characteristics :

Let's say the `Business` interface defines two complex operations:

```
interface Service {
  void doSomething();
  void doSomethingElse();
}
```

A third party provided an implementation that is partially correct :

```
final class DefaultService implements Service {
    void doSomething() { 
        // OK
    }

    void doSomethingElse() {
        // KO
    }
}
```

Since extension is not an option, I created a class that delegates to `DefaultService` the correct `doSomething()` method, and has its own implementation of `doSomethingElse()` :

```
final class IDontKnowTheName implements Service {

    private DefaultService delegate;

    void doSomething() { 
        delegate.doSomething();
    }

    void doSomethingElse() {
        // Roll new implementation here
    }
}
```

Is there a name for an "overriding/delegating" class ?

- Not an [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) since the original class `DefaultService` already implemented the `Service` interface
- Not a [Delegate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) because a method is overridden
- Not really a [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) either because some functionality of the target class is replaced, not enhanced

Comment: Possibly [`DefaultServiceProxy`](http://www.oodesign.com/proxy-pattern.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can go with a name like `DefaultServiceWrapper`, which doesn't have strong implications about delegating method calls.

However, I would choose a name that focuses on what that implementation does on its own, rather than how it delegates to the existing component.

`RollingNewImplementationService` (just kidding) would be something that I would prefer 'cause it states what it does and keeps the delegation part for itself, as an implementation detail.

This way, you won't have to change the name of the class once you decide that the original implementation of the `doSomething()` method needs to be replaced as well or if you find a way to extend the `DefaultService`.

Comment: Thumbs up, that's right. The class should be named that states what it does/represents and not how it is impemented (delegating to the third-party service).

Answer (score 1):

The point of design patterns is that they are reusable solutions to common problems. The reason people use design pattern names in class names is that with one word you can convey a lot about what problem this class is trying to solve.

Now, what problem is your class trying to solve?  It is providing a correct implementation of the `Service` interface. That is how your implementation differs from the `DefaultService`. I would argue that your class name should emphasize that, rather than the technique used to accomplish this.

So I would call it something like `CorrectService`.